# why I cannot install a content negotiation on my ktor http client?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Ive been following this:

https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#install_plugin

I want to use the ktor HTTP client for Ktor version 2.3

but when I write the code

```
val ktorClient =  HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(ContentNegotiation)
}
```

I get

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
HttpClient
Found:
RouteScopedPlugin<ContentNegotiationConfig>
```

My imports are these:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.*
```

My dependencies:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")

implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your imports, you have imported the plugin from server

```
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
```

Since you are installing in a client, you should instead import the `ContentNegotiation` from client.

```
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
```

removing the wildcard import the exact import will be like

```
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
```

Comment: I Did this mistake and your solution was a life saver for me.
Thanks